# React Bootstrap button not recognising function onClick

Tags: reactjs, function, onclick, react-bootstrap

I have a React Bootstrap app with onclick Buttons. The first 2 buttons, play and pause work. The next buttons however do not even show in the react console as having an attached function prop.

All buttons link to functions within the same scope and they are all near identical.

I've tried changing the onClick calls and reducing the unrecognised functions to `console.log`s in case it was a function breaking them.

```
class Buttons extends React.Component{
handleSelect =(e) => {
    this.props.gridSize(e);
}
render(){
    return(
        <div className="buttonsDiv">
            <ButtonToolbar>
                <button className="btn" onClick={this.props.playButton}>Play</button>
                <button className="btn" onClick={this.props.pauseButton}>Pause</button>
                <button className="btn" onClick={this.props.clear}>Clear</button>
                <button className="btn" onClick={this.props.fast}>Fast</button>
                <button className="btn" onClick={this.props.slow}>Slow</button>
                <button className="btn" onClick={this.props.seed}>Seed</button>
                <DropdownButton 
                    title="Grid Size"
                    id="size-menu"
                    onSelect={this.handleSelect} >
                    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1">20x10</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2">50x30</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="3">70x50</Dropdown.Item>
                </DropdownButton>
            </ButtonToolbar>
        </div>
    )
}
}

class Main extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.speed = 1100;
this.rows = 30;
this.cols = 50;

this.state = {
  generation: 0,
  gridFull: Array(this.rows)
    .fill()
    .map(() => Array(this.cols).fill(false)) //make array of Rows and foreach row make an array of all the columns - making a grid.
};
}

 selectBox = (row, col) =>{
  this.setState((previousState)=>{
  let {gridFull} = previousState;
  gridFull[row][col] = !gridFull[row][col]
  return {gridFull: gridFull }
  });
}

 seed = () => { 
  this.setState((prevState)=> {
      let {gridFull} = prevState;

      for (let i=0; i<this.rows; i++){
          for (let j=0; j< this.cols; j++){
              if(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) === 1){
                  gridFull[i][j] = true;
              }
          }
      }
      return {gridFull:gridFull}
  });
}

  playButton =() => {
  clearInterval(this.intervalId)
  this.intervalId = setInterval(this.play, this.speed);
}
pauseButton =() => {
   clearInterval(this.intervalId);
}

slow =() => {
  console.log('hi')
 //   this.speed=100;
 //   this.playButton();
}

fast = () => {
  console.log(this.speed)
  this.speed =1000;
  this.playButton();
}

clear = () => {
 var grid = Array(this.rows).fill().map(() => 
 Array(this.cols).fill(false));
  this.setState({
      gridFull: grid,
      generation : 0
   });
}

play = () => {
code

 }

componentDidMount(){
this.playButton();

   this.seed();
}
  render() {
  return (
   <div>
     <h1>React Application</h1>
     <Buttons playButton ={this.playButton}
             pauseButton={this.pauseButton}
     />
     <Grid
       gridFull={this.state.gridFull}
       rows={this.rows}
       selectBox={this.selectBox}
       cols={this.cols}
     />

     <h2>Generations: {this.state.generation}</h2>
   </div>
  );
}
 }
```

So in the buttons toolbar the first 2 buttons work and the rest do not even show functions as props in the react console.

As you can see they both call functions within the same scope, so I don't know what's happening.

Comment: You are not passing the later functions as props for <Button>..</Button> in the Main component

Comment: It's because you are not passing `clear,fast,slow and seed` function references in `Button` component props.

Comment: Thankyou Guys. ^^ correct answers having looked at it again >.<

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Buttons 
        playButton={this.playButton}
        pauseButton={this.pauseButton}
        clear={this.clear}
        fast={this.fast}
        slow={this.slow}
        seed={this.seed}
    />
```

Comment: I have tried this but Why do the Play and Pause Buttons work if its case of props/scope?